# Select channel from multiplexer to show temperature values in c programming

Tags: i2c, temperature, multiplexer

I have question regarding selecting channel from multiplexer. I'm trying to receive some temperature reading from the two sensors which shared the same address and while I'm using one sensor, it can work perfectly. However, when I tried to fix the second sensor onto the circuit and edit the program abit, it doesn't work. Can someone assist me?

here's the code when it starts to read:

```
void readSensor(void) {
int ch;
TWI_init_master();
for (ch=0; ch<2; ch++) 
{
TWI_start();
TWI_write_address(0xE0); // set multiplixer
TWI_write_data(0); // disable all ch    
    TWI_write_data(ch+1); // enable  ch-ch+1
    TWI_stop();
    delay100us(1);
    TWI_start();
    TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
    TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
    delay100us(1);
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_read_address(0x15);// read

    if (ch==0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
        TWI_read_data();//geting data
        readbuff[i] = recv_data;
        }

        if(!(D6T_checkPEC(readbuff, 34))) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 2; i < 34; i++) 
            {
                temp = readbuff[i];
                writeChar(temp, USB);
                delay100us(1);
            }                       
        }
    }
    else if (ch==1) 
    {

        for(i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
            TWI_read_data();//geting data
            readbuff2[i] = recv_data;
        }
        if(!(D6T_checkPEC(readbuff2, 34))) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 2; i < 34; i++) 
            {
                temp = readbuff2[i]; //readbuff 2 is defined for sensor 2, its just another array    
                writeChar(temp, USB); // Send data to the real term
                delay100us(1);
            //  delay10ms(10);  
            }
        }
    }
    TWI_stop();
    delay100us(10);
//  delay10ms(10);  
//TWI_repeated_start();// restart
//TWI_stop();   
}
//TWI_stop(); }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the type of sensor you're using and a link to the datasheet?

Comment: The sensor I'm using is omron D6T. 
The datasheet is "http://store.mansteri.com/download/datasheets/d6t_white_paper.pdf" and "http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/D6T_datasheet_Nov2012-237760.pdf"

Comment: You have quotation marks as part of your links, which causes them to fail. Also, please include a schematic of "the circuit" used to connect these sensors.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same problem. If you have solved it please share the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These sensors use an I2C interface and have a hard-coded address. You can't use two of them on the same I2C bus. You will need to create an electrically separate I2C bus for each sensor, with distinct SDA and SCL lines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have used a multiplexer to connect them. [image]

I have used this schematic diagram to guide me through for the second sensor.

The multiplexer which I'm using is stated on the diagram, PCA9548A(8ch). The datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9548a.pdf

Comment: This should have been an edit to your question rather than posted as an answer. You can go back and edit your question at any time to add additional information.

Comment: If you want to supply additional information and images, update your original post and add the information there, instead of posting it as an answer.  Comments work for this too, although you can't inline images into a comment.